# MySQL SELECT WHERE datetime matches time (and not necessarily day)

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, match

I have a table which contains a timestamp column. I wish to return all records of a given time regardless of the date.

In other words i want to fetch all records where time is greater then 09:43:00

```
2015-11-02 09:41:43
2015-11-02 09:43:02
2015-11-02 09:48:27
2015-11-02 09:52:49
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id from table where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME(timestamp_col)) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIME('09:43:00'))
```

OR

```
SELECT id from table where TIME(timestamp_col) > TIME('09:43:00')
```

OR

```
SELECT id from table where TIME(timestamp_col) > '09:43:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,modified_on FROM table
where date_format(modified_on,'%H:%i:%s') > '09:43:30'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name>
WHERE date_format(timestamp_col,'%H:%i:%s') > '09:43:00'
```